# Windows Service starts then immediately stops (code issue?)

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, wcf, windows-services

I made the below Service with WCF and installed as per the specified way in the MSDN "[making a windows service](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zt39148a.aspx)" tutorial, BUT each time i go to start the service i get a pop up that states that the service started and stopped. I'm wondering why this is happening and how to rectify it.

Service Code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Linq;
using System.ServiceProcess;
using System.Text;
using System.ServiceModel;
using System.ServiceModel.Description;
using RemoteArchiverService;
namespace ORService
{
    public partial class ORservice : ServiceBase
    {
        private ServiceHost ORAHost;
        public ORservice()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }
        protected override void OnStart(string[] args)
        {
            if (ORAHost != null)
            {
                ORAHost.Close();
            }
            // Open the ServiceHostBase to start listening for commands
            ORAHost = new ServiceHost(typeof(OrionWCF));
            ORAHost.Open();
        }
        protected override void OnStop()
        {
            ORAHost.Close();//stop listening
        }
    }
    [ServiceContract(Namespace = "http://Blah.Blargh.ServiceBase")]
    public interface IRemoteArchive
    {
        //functions
        [OperationContract]
        void CollectFilesAsync(DateTime start, DateTime end);
        [OperationContract]
        void ChangeExpireCheck(int daysToKeep);
        [OperationContract]
        void UpdateActiveProfiles(Profile P, bool AddRemove);
        [OperationContract]
        void UpdateProfileList(Profile P, bool AddRemove);
    }
    partial class OrWCF : IRemoteArchive
    {
        private List<Profile> ProfileList = new List<Profile>();
        private List<Profile> ActiveProfiles = new List<Profile>();
        private int DaysToKeepData = 30;

        public void UpdateProfileList(Profile P, bool AddRemove)
        {
            ...
        }
        public void UpdateActiveProfiles(Profile P, bool AddRemove)
        {
            ...
        }
        public void ChangeExpireCheck(int daysToKeep)
        {
            ...
        }
        public void CollectFilesAsync(DateTime start, DateTime end)
        {
            ...
        }
    }
}
```

Log Readout:

> Service cannot be started. System.InvalidOperationException: Service
>   'RemoteService.OrWCF' has zero application
>   (non-infrastructure) endpoints. This might be because no configuration
>   file was found for your application, or because no service element
>   matching the service name could be found in the configuration file, or
>   because no endpoints were defined in the service element.    at
>   System.ServiceModel.Description.DispatcherBuilder.EnsureThereAreApplicationEndpoints(ServiceDescription
>   description)    at
>   System.ServiceModel.Description.DispatcherBuilder.InitializeServiceHost(ServiceDescription
>   description, ServiceHostBase serviceHost)    at
>   System.ServiceModel.ServiceHostBase.InitializeRuntime()    at
>   System.ServiceModel.ServiceHostBase.OnBeginOpen()    at
>   System.ServiceModel.ServiceHostBase.OnOpen(TimeSpan timeout)    at
>   System.ServiceModel.Channels.CommunicationObject.Open(TimeSpan
>   timeout)    at System.ServiceModel.Channels.CommunicationObject.Open()
>   at RemoteService.ORservice.OnStart(String[] args) in C:\Us...

Comment: What does the application log say? Run eventvwr to find out... then tell us.

Comment: edited to include Log info

Comment: Your configuration is OK ? can u add it ? what binding you use ? what are the endpoints ?

Comment: figured out. I hadn't implemented any hosting

Answer (score 1):

Enable WCF tracing to see detail about issue.

```
<configuration>
   <system.diagnostics>
      <sources>
            <source name="System.ServiceModel" 
                    switchValue="Information, ActivityTracing"
                    propagateActivity="true">
            <listeners>
               <add name="traceListener" 
                   type="System.Diagnostics.XmlWriterTraceListener" 
                   initializeData= "c:\log\Traces.svclog" />
            </listeners>
         </source>
      </sources>
   </system.diagnostics>
</configuration>
```

For detail on WCF configuration see [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms733025.aspx).

EDIT based on new info:
it is not able to find WCF service endpoint configuration in App.Config file, see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms733932.aspx.

Comment: I did just add the log issue from event viewer if that is useful